# Strict mode for JScript?

Tags: jscript, wsh

Is there something in JScript (used in Windows Script Host) that is similar to `"use strict";` in JavaScript?

In particular, I want to prevent this:

```
var goodVar = 2;
misspelledVar = 3;
```

JScript will happily execute this without any warning or error.

Comment: WSH is probably going to be stuck with the same old javascript engine forever because of compatibility concerns.